# Every pages are shown 404 page on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-error-pages

Now, I am building a WordPress site.
After creating a new page, click preview button, the 404 page are shown.
I 'am working on WordPress 5.9.7 and using a child theme of Twenty Twenty-Two.
And I set permalik as "Post name".
[image]

After editing the "About Us" page, for example, then clicking the preview button, the 404 page are shown.
Following is the setting of url for about us page.
[image]

The result likes following.
[image]

If I use Plan setting as permalinks, it works very well.

If you have any methods, please write your methods.
Thank you.